# Passing a simple javascript variable to php file

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, laravel-5

I want to pass a simple javascript variable to another php file which is a controller file in laravel.

For example: below is a code from my blade.php file of laravel.

```
<script>
    function getLocation() {

        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        } else {
            alert('Geolocation is not supported by this browser.');
        }
    }

    function showPosition(position) {
        var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        var longitude =position.coords.longitude;

        var dataString = 'latitude'+latitude+'longitude'+longitude;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "PagesController.php",
            data: dataString
        });
    }
    getLocation();
</script>
```

As latitude and longitude are not form values then how should I catch these values in controller file named as PagesController.php of laravel.

Comment: Yes, it can be done with AJAX / Json.

Comment: data: {"Data" : dataString} should be the syntax, than simply access it on the target page with $_POST['Data']

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "PagesController.php",
    data: {latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude},
});
```

and on PagesController.php

```
$latitude = $_REQUEST['latitude'];
$longitude = $_REQUEST['longitude'];
```

Comment: It shows me an error message as 'undefined index latitude and longitude'.

Comment: @Amarja try to alert the value of latitude and longitude before sending it to ajax to test if it has value

Comment: @Amarja can you update your defition starting from how you generate your latitude and longitude so that I can analyze it :)

Comment: I have updated the changes with detailed information.

Comment: My given code to you works for me. I test it now. I can get the latitude and longitude on php part. here's my codes
[javascript-code](http://pastebin.com/gxL89Gpk) and [php-code](http://pastebin.com/XviY16xL)

Answer (score 0):

Form value submissions simply send formatted data via a http request. You can also do this using javascript(jQuery makes it easier).

Set up the php file that will accept the variable on your server. The php file should look something like this:

File: `calculations.php` (You can name it whatever you want)

```
<?php

$dataString = $_POST['dataString'];

// your calculations here

echo $result;

?>
```

Then use jQuery to make an ajax request to your php file and pass the variable to your php file.

```
$.ajax({url: 'calculations.php', data:{dataString:dataString} type:'POST', success: function(result){
   console.log(result); // will output the $result 
}});
```

After the calculations are done the function stored in the `success` field will be executed, and whatever you echo'ed out in the php file will be stored in the `result` variable in your javascript.

Further reading: [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)